# If intellij sbt auto import, then no need to refresh manually?

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

In Intellij, if we make any changes in build.sbt, then we need to refresh it manually. Unless we enable the sbt auto import option. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is correct.
To quote the [Scala Plugin Blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2013/11/18/built-in-sbt-support-in-intellij-idea-13/):

> Don’t forget to use Enable auto-import checkbox to have your IntelliJ IDEA project automatically synchronized with .sbt files.